# def double (num): """ function to double the number """ return 2 * num print double (10)

Tags: function, return, user-defined-functions, return-value

def double (num):
"""
function to double the number
"""
return 2 * num
print double (10)

#getting error like this, Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?

rewrite the code and checked also tried with parentheses

Comment: `print(double(10))` should work, i.e., with parentheses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.